# Gridview -Problem

Tags: c#, gridview

I have three fields being displayed in the gridview.  Depending on the value of first field, I have to either display or hide the second two fields.

The following code is what I've tried so far but I don't know how to get the full solution.

Could anybody have a look please?

The three fields are

1) activeStatus

2)DateMadeInactive

3)Comments

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType  == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 
            bool activeStatus=Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Active"));
            if(activeStatus)
            {
               // I need to display the activeStatus columns    
            }
           else
           {
               // I need to hide activeStatus Column and Display the DatemadeInactive     and  Comments
           }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put conditionals into template fields:

```
  <asp:GridView ... runat="server">
    <Columns>
      ... your other fields ...
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
        <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:Label Text='<%# (bool)Eval("Active")
                               ? Eval("activeStatus") 
                               : Eval("DateMadeInactive", "Inactive since {0}") %>'
            runat="server"/> 

        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I gather from your question is you want to know how to hide or display any given column in a DataGridView.  If so, you just need to add the column to the DataGridView, either with a DataSource or manually, and then hide any columns you don't want by doing the following:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: I have used this but, If we have two records with Active status True and False in Same Page then It doesn't work.. Thank s anyway though!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  What did you expect would happen? What actually happened when you tried it?

Comment: if there are two records in a page with activeStatus Value = True and False, It is not hiding the columns so the purpose of making it visible is not correct. I have to take other approach, Its not that your code is working , it's the approach itself is not working. So I have to take the blame , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this using, IIRC, the CellFormatting event. It gives you an opportunity to test the value of each cell and replace it or other cells in the row based on that. In my case I was replacing numeric values with looked-up strings and altering background color.